# How to show batch no on application icon?

Tags: iphone, android, batch-file, icons

In iPhone we can show the batch number on the application icon. i want to do the same thing for Android application icon.

I have seen the same thing in Android "Message" application icon. I you receive one message, it will show "1" on the icon.

We can use [Widget](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html) to do this. But I don't want to use [Widget](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html).

Is there any possibility to do this without widgets ?

Please give some idea about this.

Comment: Well, this is android. It has its own style. You can't do this I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any possibility to do this without widgets ?

No, sorry.

BTW, they are called "app widgets". "Widgets" are things like `EditText` and `Button`.